# How can I view my webcam in vista?

Tags: windows-vista, webcam

I have a cheep Logitech webcam that works fine in Skype and flash applications. In windows xp I could open the webcam in my computer and view though it and save pictures. Does Vista do that as well?

And if not what's a good simple program that I can use to replicate this functionality?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Since it looks like the functionality you are expecting is not available in Windows Vista, you can use [VLC](http://videolan.org) to open the camera as a "Capture Device" and then take snapshots using VLC. The [VLC FAQ](http://www.videolan.org/support/faq.html) explains tells us that to take a snapshot:

> **How can I take screenshots?**
>
> To take a snapshot of the video
>   displayed by VLC, you just need to
>   press the pre-defined snapshot hotkey:
>
> - Windows / Linux / Unix: <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>S</kbd>
> - Mac OS X: <kbd>Command</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>s</kbd>
>
> To change it, go to *Preferences ->
>   Interface -> Hotkeys* settings, check
>   Advanced options, and set Take video
>   snapshot.
>
> You can also take a snaphot via the
>   menu *Video -> Snapshot*.
>
> To change the snapshot format or
>   directory, go to *Preferences -> Video*.
>
> **Where are my screenshots?**
>
> If you haven't changed the snapshot
>   directory in your preferences, your
>   screenshots should go to:
>
> - Windows: `My Documents\My Pictures\`
> - Linux / Unix: `$(HOME)/.vlc/`
> - Mac OS X: `Desktop/`
>
> To change it, go to *Preferences ->
>   Video -> Video snapshot directory*.

Answer (score 4):

You can't do that in Vista as the WIA driver installed on XP is not included with Vista, it is [by design](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/927833).

Answer (score 0):

Use Yawcam, AmCap or Debut Video Capture for this.
All these are free and simple. Yawcam requires Java, however.

EDIT: OK, here is some more info re. above apps.

Yawcam can capture both photos and videos, and can be used for motion detection too.
(capture video only if movement is detected)

I have not used AmCap much, but it is a often used and popular app.

RE Debut Video Capture, it used to be a Trial, but now it has a free version too, so you can use it without paying (for non-commercial purposes). It has more features, for example besides being able to capture webcam photos/video, it can also make video recordings of your Windows desktop/screen.
It does this very well - you can specify the captured video file format, and also capture all or just part of the screen, and also it is great for software demos, as it shows left/right mouse button clicks in the video, plus shows a yellow spot around the mouse pointer.

Comment: Would be great if you could improve your answer by giving a bit of context, e.g. how to use the app, what it does, how they compare, etc.