# How can I record and take shots with a webcam in Windows 7?

Tags: windows-7, webcam

I just plugged in the Microsoft webcam to my PC but I can't see any application to record a movie or take snapshots. In Windows XP there used to be a option in My Computer.

Are there any settings related to this?

My model is VX-700, it is working fine with Google and Skype... but how do I record directly?

Comment: What is the name/model of the webcam? Microsoft *should* have a page dedicated for the drivers and software for the device.

Comment: Model is vx-700

Comment: possible duplicate of [How can I view my webcam in vista?](http://superuser.com/questions/65367/how-can-i-view-my-webcam-in-vista)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just found a good video recorder software I am answering this, so that it might be help full to others as well

[Debut video capture software](http://www.nchsoftware.com/capture/index.html)
Basic free version

Answer (score 2):

> I just plugged in the microsoft web cam to my Pc but i can't see any application to record the movie or take snap, **in xp there used to be a option in the my computer**
>
> Is there any setting related to this ?

It's not possible to take screenshots natively in Windows 7. You will need a third party utility